# How do I authorise requests to my GAE REST server?

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-app-engine, rest

What's the best technology for to authorise request made by my app/website to my server?

I want only my website and app to be able to communicate with my GAE server.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the GAE Endpoints service?  IMO, the two big advantages of it are that it simplifies:

- the provision of web services to multiple clients type, including Android, web, and iOS,
- the use of OATH2 for client authorization (either Google User authorization, or just app authorization).

I mention it because both of these seem to apply to your situation.

Note though that endpoints is still in preview, and they really mean it.  It was released more then a year ago and it has been a bumpy road.